# Why is Azure Data Factory SharePoint Online List Linked Service Connecting without Error, but not Showing Preview Data

Tags: azure-data-factory, sharepoint-online

I am attempting to use a SharePoint Online list as a data source in an Azure Data Factory pipeline.  I can get it to connect, but it shows no data.

Background:
I have established an Azure Data Factory Copy Data Activity and Linked Service to do so per the Microsoft documentation:
[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties)

As it instructs, I established an App, set up its secret in the Azure Vault, have an integrated runtime, and established the Apps permissions on the SharePoint site. It now connects without error and returns the list of assets in Azure Data Factory when clicking the "List name" drop down list in the Linked Service Connection tab.

What is not working is the "Preview data" link.  After clicking, it attempts to get the data, but returns an empty object with the screen message of "No Data to Preview".  (There are a couple of hundred rows in the list.)

[image]

I explored using a query and confirmed through its syntax that it is connecting and even validating all column names of the List - it just is not returning data.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error of my ways.  In the dialog where you configure the permissions at the SharePoint page, I was replacing the Scope parameter with a string based on my instance of SharePoint page-a poor assumption on my part.  Although this would allow a connection without error and provide the names of the lists, it would not return the data from a list.

As found, the Scope parameter is intended to be typed exactly as is without modification.  Doing that, it worked perfectly.

[image]

Note:  I learned this by putting in a support ticket as suggested.  Microsoft's support is awesome when you put in a ticket under an Azure subscription!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue in my environment and able to get the data from `SharePoint Online List`  and able to get the data to get the data from `SharePoint Online List` follow below steps:

1. Register a application with the Microsoft Identity platform (Azure Active Directory). Take note of the following values, which you will use to define the associated service:

   - Application ID
   - Application key
   - Tenant ID
2. Permit your registered application to access SharePoint Online. follow this [Allow app to access SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites).

**My lists and the no item in each list:**

[image]

**In ADF I am using this list only which have 2 items:**

[image]

**I am able to preview the data correctly.**

[image]

---

**If still issue persist :**

- check your data if it is available in list, or in proper format.
- Or raise a [support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket) for deeper investigation.

Comment: Thanks - I put in a support ticket and they found the error in my ways.  Posted below.